# How do you setup multi-mon support in VirtualBox machine

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, virtualbox

I am a heavy VirtualBox user.  I run VirtualBox on a Windows 7 host and mostly Windox XP guests...but some linux and others as well.

When using my Windowx XP guests, I REALLY miss the multi-monitor support you get when not in a VM.

I would love to be pointed to some step-by-step instructions for getting this to reliably work for my Windows XP guest VMs.

Any thoughts?

Seth

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Virtualbox 3.2.x or 4.x, this feature is available out of the box, with no complicated setup. From [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/109485/virtualbox-to-use-dual-monitors):

> Basic Setup:
>
> 1. Power off your virtual machine if it's on.
> 2. From the main VirtualBox window, select your VM and choose Settings.
> 3. Choose display.
> 4. Below "Video Memory" is Monitor Count. Slide it to 2, and adjust 1.
>    your video memory if VirtualBox
>    complains.
> 5. Start your guest and perform the standard "Extend the desktop onto 1.
>    this display" method based on the
>    Guest OS. (Guest Additions need to 1.
>    be installed.)
> 6. A second "Oracle VM VirtualBox" window will appear with the second
>    display. You can resize it however you
>    want.

Comment: This worked beautifully for me and gives me the "truest" dual monitor experience (versus resizes the guest window).

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [Seamless Mode](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#seamlesswindows) and just place the individual virtualized application windows on your existing multi-monitor setup.

Comment: +1 for the greatest idea! I never thought about this, and I'll try it as soon as possible. Very clever, I really hope that will be TEH hit!

Answer (score 3):

You can try the suggestions from this thread (only works with XP guests):

**[Effectively using Virtualbox with Dual-Monitor-Host](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=17524)**

Or (and this the easy way out) simply resize the VirtualBox and span it over two monitors (but do increase the shared video memory).

[image]

([View bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjdkr.jpg))

Comment: Boo! Who wants to use the easy and logical way to span 2 monitors! I prefer overly complex solutions

Comment: yep, complex solutions are great ... IF you get them working! :D

Comment: I do this all the time. Since my win-7 taskbar is only on my left monitor, I snap the VM window to the left screen edge, and drag the right edge to the far right. Only annoyance is that many dialogs pop to the screen center and so get split by the bezels.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like multiple monitors are only supported for the [VBoxHeadless Frontend](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vboxheadless). According to the [VirtualBox User Manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#advanced-multimonitor):

> VirtualBox allows the guest to use
>   multiple virtual monitors. Up to
>   sixty-four virtual monitors are
>   supported.
>
> **Note:**
>
> 1. Multiple monitors currently work only with Windows XP guests, and Guest
>      Additions must be installed, as the
>      implementation resides in the Guest
>      Additions video driver.
> 2. Multiple monitors work only with the VBoxHeadless frontend. You must
>      also enable VRDP multiconnection mode
>      ([see the section called “VRDP multiple
>      connections”](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vrdp-multiconnection)) to access two or more VM
>      displays when the guest is using
>      multiple monitors.
> 3. The guest video RAM size should be increased when multiple monitors
>      are used. The VRAM is shared among the
>      virtual monitors so that only part of
>      it is available for each one.
>      Therefore the available resolutions
>      and color depths will be reduced if
>      the VRAM size remains the same and
>      multiple monitors are enabled.

Comment: I don't think this information is correct any longer. Your link is broken - here is a link to the relevant info for v4 http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-display