# virtualbox seamless mode on multiple monitors without VRDP

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtualbox, microsoft-virtual-pc, virtual-desktop, seamless

Is there any type of emulation software, like VirtualBox, VMWare, etc... that supports seamless mode on multiple monitors? I saw  the [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/109485/virtualbox-to-use-dual-monitors) but the answer involves connecting to the windows machine with RDP, which I don't want to do. Is there any other way?

If not, for what reason does it not work? From what I understand about computers, it doesn't seem like it should make a difference whether it would work on 2 monitors vs 1 monitor...

Answer (score 1):

VMware Workstation does this sort of thing just fine. Currently using it with various virtual machines spanning across 4 monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any kind of work out there for what you are asking for, and quite plainly, I don't have a second monitor to even experiment with to try and help you, however as for the second half of the question, I believe I can help there.

Virtualization software, like VirtualBox and VMWare, does just what it's name implies. It creates a virtual machine for you to run an operating system within. Your operating system within there has no idea what video card you are using, how many monitors you have connected, or even if you have a mouse or not. What it sees is the virtual monitor, keyboard, mouse, network card, sound card, possibly even the virtual USB ports if you got them enabled.

As far as the OS you installed within the virtualization software is concerned, you have only one monitor. One sound card. One set of speakers. etc., etc., etc. In order for what you are looking for to be available, a second monitor adapter would have to be coded into your virtualization software of choice.

Comment: I get that it's just emulating one monitor. but couldn't virtualbox pretend that one monitor spanned the entire 3 monitors I have? if you have it not in seamless mode, you can certainly drag the window to cover all of them..