# Enable the second screen after increasing the monitor count in Vagrant with VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors, vagrant

I can see how to enable multiple displays with vagrant in this answer: https://superuser.com/a/207291/662918, but it seems after doing that I still need to go to `View > Virtual Screen 2 > Enable` in the VirtualBox gui to get the second screen to actually show.

Is there a way to enable virtual screen 2 from my Vagrantfile so that the second screen will be enabled without the user having to ever touch the VirtualBox gui?