# Setting up multiple monitors for Windows 10 Enterprise in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, multiple-monitors

I have created a VirtualBox VM where the host is running Windows 10 and the guest is running Windows 10 Enterprise

I am trying to get this to use multiple monitors, but having Zero luck even when finding questions that have already been asked and doing the same thing

[VirtualBox to use dual monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/109485/virtualbox-to-use-dual-monitors)

As it stands, I have the VM set to be;

Windows 10 (64-bit), using 3 displays, 256mb video memory, 3 on monitor count, all monitors at 100% scaling, VBoxSVGA graphics controller, 3D acceleration enabled

No matter what I do, the option for screens 2&3 to enable (when not in full screen mode) are greyed out, will not display when I set to use host screens 2&3 respectively when in full screen and the main screen ignores my 1920x1080 resolution and sticks at 1600x1200

Comment: Are you saying you tried the steps in the answer you've linked but they are not working as expected or described?

Comment: I have done the steps yes, and with the desired result to be able to use 3 monitors, this has not been the case