# Setting Virtualbox "monitors number" to 2 - input locked

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, multiple-monitors

I am following [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/109485/virtualbox-to-use-dual-monitors) on how to open a Virtual box with two (virtual) monitors (=two windows, each correspondig to a monitor), so that I can display them on two physical monitors.

I am running Ubuntu on Virtualbox, on Windows 10.

I have my 2 physical monitors up and running (Windows settings: `Display > multiple displays > extend these displays`), I have my VM shut down.

Following `step 4`, I go to `Virtualbox > My VM > settings > screen > number of monitors`, but this parameter is locked, I cannot slide the bar.

Why is it locked? How can I unlock it?

Comment: Instruction 1 is what people often miss… shut it down, don't 'pause' it.

Comment: Thanks, if you want you can type it as as answer and I will flag it as correct.

Comment: Welcome - no worries, your answer looks good to me. Remember to mark it as 'accepted' once the timer on it runs down [I don't think it will let you do it straight away]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

I was actually misinterpreting `step 1`:

I was **shutting down** my VM from Virtual Box

```
right click on the VM > shut down > save state
```

while I had to **power off** the VM from the VM window:

```
Ubuntu OS interface bar > power off/logout > power off...
```

[image]

Then, after my VM had rebooted, I had to go to

```
VM window > window upper bar > View
```

and here I can see two options: virtual display 1, virtual display 2.

Here I had to select

```
virtual display 2 > Enable
```

and another window opens, with a second screen.