# How to make VirtualBox start with two monitors by default?

Tags: virtualbox

Whenever I boot my VM I have to exit full screen, enable display 2, minimise it, move it to the left, maximise it, go into my guest display settings, extend my desktop, enable full screen.

(Also, whenever I switch out of full screen mode my second display disappears and I have to repeat the process).

Is there a way to start my VM so VirtualBox remembers the number and placement of the last used displays please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualBox to use dual monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/109485/virtualbox-to-use-dual-monitors)

Comment: No, it's not the same at all

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Could you explain why it should be?

Comment: Thank you for this exchange. I'm finished here.